# Vue/Javascript: When scrolled to top of page, scroll further to show additional nav bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, vue.js

basically what I would like to archieve is what [Snapzu.com](http://snapzu.com) is doing: When you have reached the top of the window, you can scroll further to show - in this case - different categories.

I would like to do exactly that using Vue or Javascript in general, but so far I haven't figured out what to do.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the scroll event for your document and check if you have reached the top, and then manipulate the DOM to add this additional navbar.

Just like the site you linked made it. In this screenshot, you can see in firefox inspect that they have an scroll event that makes what I described above.

[image: Firefox inspection showing an event to the document for mouseScroll]